# Question considering the covering map of the circle $S^1$ in Munkres, 2. edition

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The map $p: R \rightarrow S^1$ given by the equation $p(x) = (\cos 2\pi x,\sin 2\pi x)$

And we are to consider the subset U of $S^1$ consisting of those points having positive first coordinate. Then they say that the set $p^{-1}(U)$, consisting of those points x for which $\cos 2\pi x$ is positive is the union of the intervals

$$V_n = \left(n-\frac{1}{4}, n + \frac{1}{4}\right)$$

This is what it need to have explained: Further they say that, restricted to the closed interval $\bar{V_n}$, p carries $\bar{V_n}$ surjectively onto $\bar{U}$ and $V_n$ to U, by the intermediate value theorem.  How is this?

It further says that since $\bar{V_n}$ is compact, $p \restriction{\bar{V_n}}$ is a homeomorphism of $\bar{V_n}$ with $\bar{U}$. How is this?

Comment: Using the intermediate value theorem seems like massive overkill to me. Simply observe the restrictions of the functions $\cos(2 \pi x)$ and $\sin(2 \pi x)$ to the open interval $(n-1/4,n+1/4)$ and to its closure $[n-1/4,n+1/4]$, using what you know about the cosine and the sine and their graphs.